# phonegap & cordova the docs are out of date which do I do

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

In some cases I see phonegap.js in some I see cordova.js and in the rest I see both. Amongst them all I see arguments of which to use over the other, or it should be one or the other. But no one seems to say "Well, this worked for me".

With that I see many of things about the config.xml. features vs plugins, how to configure the XML but again nothing about what worked when and how. I have found some of the newer documents for phonegap. But its just mostly how to use the scripts to your favor.

Also phonegap.js I couldnt find that with my install I had to go out and find it, found it on github. I think its an older copy as well. So with that if I do have to use one or the other or both. Is there a newer copy what where?

I am using Phonegap 3.0.0 or in the 3 dot series somewhere as far as I know (what ever the current latest version is.

Answer (score 0):

i am new to phonegap, but i found out that it depends on the way you create your project what js you get.
if you create it with cordova create hello... then you will get cordova.js. If you create it with phonegap create hello... then you get both of them phonegap.js and cordova.js

Comment: Yea its very frustrating how all over the place the docs are, and some seem controdictive of others even in the same version docs. You think being backed by such a large company like Adobe they'd clean that up some, and provide some better insight.

Comment: each time in run a new build its a different out come.. sometimes Ill end up with two config.xml for example, one at the app level and one in the www, other times I wont.. each time the config.xml be it just one or two will be different everytime..

Comment: Yea its really confusing. I am also stuck with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490670/cordova-phonegap-3-0-device-properties